# Issue in dropdown box (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have 5 images for swiping, and need to add dropdown box for all the 5 image pages in html, for the first image slide dropdown box is fixed in size and clickable but for the remaining four image page the dropdown box is small and also not clickable, this seems to be odd issue, googled alot but could not get a solution related to my issue.

**css**

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
 body {
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
}
.swiper-container {
width: 90%;
height: 100%;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}

.red-slide {
 background: "file:///android_res/drawable/r9.jpg";

 }
.blue-slide {
 background: "file:///android_res/drawable/br.jpeg";
 }
 .orange-slide {
 background: "file:///android_res/drawable/br.jpeg";
 }
.green-slide {
 background: "bb1.jpg";
 }
.pink-slide {
 background: "bb1.jpg";
 }
 .swiper-slide .title {
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 42px;
 margin-top: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 line-height: 45px;
 }
.pagination {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 20;
 left: 10px;
 bottom: 10px;
  }
 .swiper-pagination-switch {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #222;
 margin-right: 5px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-visible-switch {
 background: #aaa;
  }
 .swiper-active-switch {
 background: #fff;
 }

   .wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    }

 .button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  }
```

**html**

```
  <body style="padding:0px 0px;">
  <div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
     <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/a.jpg" >
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="button" >
 <div id="ddmenu">
  <ul>                
    <li>SHARE
        <div>
            <div class="column">
                <a id="sendFacebook" onclick="share(3)" href="#">Email</a>
                <a id="sendMMS" onclick="share1(3)" href="#">MMS</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>      
  </ul>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>

  <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
      <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/b.jpg" >
    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="button" >
<div id="ddmenu">
<ul>                
    <li>SHARE
        <div>
            <div class="column">
                <a id="sendFacebook" onclick="share(4)" href="#">Email</a>
                <a id="sendMMS" onclick="share1(4)" href="#">MMS</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>      
  </ul>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: div id -> Means there is only ONE on the page
div class -> Multiple on the page

I can see you have multiple ID's with the same name. Try changing those to classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i got your point and also i changed the id #ddmenu by .ddmenu in css file, but still not able to get it, because in js file there is function called getElementsbyId @ThomasWood

Comment: A simple fix would be to give them a 'ddMenu' class, and a 'ddMenu-#' ID